# tab_to_string [Error] Execution (37: 13): ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Tags: sql, oracle

I've found the tab_to_string from other Q/A for aggregation values. hope this can solve the problem but it seems something is not right.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE FMF_VERIFY5.t_varchar2_tab AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FMF_tab_to_string (p_varchar2_tab  IN  t_varchar2_tab,
                                          p_delimiter     IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',') RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  l_string     VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN p_varchar2_tab.FIRST .. p_varchar2_tab.LAST LOOP
    IF i != p_varchar2_tab.FIRST THEN
      l_string := l_string || p_delimiter;
    END IF;
    l_string := l_string || p_varchar2_tab(i);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN l_string;
END tab_to_string;
/

SELECT ID, tab_to_string(CAST(COLLECT(COMMENTS ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS t_varchar2_tab),'//') AS COMMENTS
FROM TABLE
```

Above SELECT query works time to time based on the input value. it looks like when comment has big data it throws an error.

COMMENT is varchar(1024)
and there can be up to 20 comments.

Comment: My assumption is that you're exceeding the allowed length of a `varchar2`.  You could potentially change the code to return a `clob` but that might require changes to the calling application.  Depending on the version of Oracle you're using, you would likely be better off using the `listagg` function rather than this home-grown process.

Comment: Hi Justin, I believe LISTAGG can cover only up to 4000 bytes. Isn't it? I use 11g and cannot handle overflow. and would like to have more than 4000 bytes.

Comment: one more thing, I don't mind to change the code to return a clob if that can handle up to 32767 bytes which is max length that can be fit in a excel cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query for getting a comment in clob and restrict the size to 32767.

```
SELECT
    LENGTH(LIST),
    LIST
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            SUBSTR(RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, COMMENT, ',').EXTRACT('//text()')).GETCLOBVAL(), ','), 1, 32767) AS LIST
        FROM
            MYTABLE
    );
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=613416e5d697ab0c5a7bc876495b0fa5)

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks Tejash for the tip. I was able to move to the next query... btw, I have question. when I do left join this table(X) this clob column assigned to empty. Select x.id, x.list from y left join x on x.id=y.id  x.id is not clob and it get value as expected but x.list has empty value even though i can see y value when i run only that part.

Comment: @Julia, Glad that you moved to the next level. Your question is not clear to me. Can you please re-frame it so that I can insight?

Comment: I've posted as new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844983/failed-to-get-clob-column-value-when-left-join. Can you please take a look?